# My application isn't working smoothly

Tags: android, metadata, handler

I am trying to develop a application. It is a radio application. When i use a method to show meta data that time it is creating some problem.
1.Play Pause button are not working smoothly.
2.Taking more time to show layout.

here is the main activity code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;

import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IRadioActivity extends Activity implements
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener, MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener {

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    private MediaPlayer mp = null;

    private ImageButton btnPlay;

    String title;
    String artist;

    private static Context con;
    Timer timer;
    TextView StationName;
    String Stationurl = "http://95.211.82.139:8048";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        IRadioActivity.con = this;

        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important


        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // check for already playing
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.pause();
                        // Changing button image to play button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Resume song
                    if (mp != null) {
                        mp.start();
                        // Changing button image to pause button
                        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        playSong();
        getMeta();
    }


    public void playSong() {
        // Play song



        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(Stationurl);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

            // Displaying Song title

            // Changing Button Image to pause image
            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);


        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // ----------------
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
        switch (what) {
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            sb.append("Server Died");
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            sb.append("Unknown");
            break;
        default:
            sb.append(" Non standard (");
            sb.append(what);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
        sb.append(extra);
        Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
        return true;
    }

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "PlayerService onBufferingUpdate : " + percent + "%");
    }

    // .....top bar button....//



    public void getMeta() {

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                URL url;
                // Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                try {
                    // url = new URL("http://relay5.slayradio.org:8000");
                    url = new URL(Stationurl);
                    final IcyStreamMeta icy = new IcyStreamMeta(url);


                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            // Typeface book = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                            // getAssets(), "fonts/Neutra2Text-Book.otf");

                            final TextView songTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songName);
                            final TextView artistName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artistName);
                            try {



                                artistName.setText(icy.getArtist().toString()
                                        .trim());
                                artistName.setText(icy.getArtist().toString()
                                        .trim());
                                songTitle.setText(icy.getTitle().toString()
                                        .trim());

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }



                        }
                    });

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, 0, 500);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Facing those problems when i use getMeta(); method.

Main Class for this method is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IcyStreamMeta<Message> {

    protected URL streamUrl;
    private Map<String, String> metadata;
    private boolean isError;

    public IcyStreamMeta(URL streamUrl) {
        setStreamUrl(streamUrl);

        isError = false;
    }

    /**
     * Get artist using stream's title
     *
     * @return String
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String getArtist() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

        if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
            return "";

        String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
        String title = streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-"));
        return title.trim();
    }

    /**
     * Get title using stream's title
     *
     * @return String
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String getTitle() throws IOException {
        Map<String, String> data = getMetadata();

        if (!data.containsKey("StreamTitle"))
            return "";

        String streamTitle = data.get("StreamTitle");
        String artist = streamTitle.substring(streamTitle.indexOf("-")+1);
        return artist.trim();
    }

    public Map<String, String> getMetadata() throws IOException {
        if (metadata == null) {
            refreshMeta();
        }

        return metadata;
    }

    public void refreshMeta() throws IOException {
        retreiveMetadata();
    }

    private void retreiveMetadata() throws IOException {
        URLConnection con = streamUrl.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("Icy-MetaData", "1");
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", null);
        con.connect();

        int metaDataOffset = 0;
        Map<String, List<String>> headers = con.getHeaderFields();
        InputStream stream = con.getInputStream();

        if (headers.containsKey("icy-metaint")) {
            // Headers are sent via HTTP
            metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(headers.get("icy-metaint").get(0));
        } else {
            // Headers are sent within a stream
            StringBuilder strHeaders = new StringBuilder();
            char c;
            while ((c = (char)stream.read()) != -1) {
                strHeaders.append(c);
                if (strHeaders.length() > 5 && (strHeaders.substring((strHeaders.length() - 4), strHeaders.length()).equals("\r\n\r\n"))) {
                    // end of headers
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Match headers to get metadata offset within a stream
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\r\\n(icy-metaint):\\s*(.*)\\r\\n");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strHeaders.toString());
            if (m.find()) {
                metaDataOffset = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
            }
        }

        // In case no data was sent
        if (metaDataOffset == 0) {
            isError = true;
            return;
        }

        // Read metadata
        int b;
        int count = 0;
        int metaDataLength = 4080; // 4080 is the max length
        boolean inData = false;
        StringBuilder metaData = new StringBuilder();
        // Stream position should be either at the beginning or right after headers
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            count++;

            // Length of the metadata
            if (count == metaDataOffset + 1) {
                metaDataLength = b * 16;
            }

            if (count > metaDataOffset + 1 && count < (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {              
                inData = true;
            } else {                
                inData = false;             
            }               
            if (inData) {               
                if (b != 0) {                   
                    metaData.append((char)b);               
                }           
            }               
            if (count > (metaDataOffset + metaDataLength)) {
                break;
            }

        }

        // Set the data
        metadata = IcyStreamMeta.parseMetadata(metaData.toString());

        // Close
        stream.close();
    }

    public boolean isError() {
        return isError;
    }

    public URL getStreamUrl() {
        return streamUrl;
    }

    public void setStreamUrl(URL streamUrl) {
        this.metadata = null;
        this.streamUrl = streamUrl;
        this.isError = false;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> parseMetadata(String metaString) {
        Map<String, String> metadata = new HashMap();
        String[] metaParts = metaString.split(";");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([a-zA-Z]+)=\\'([^\\']*)\\'$");
        Matcher m;
        for (int i = 0; i < metaParts.length; i++) {
            m = p.matcher(metaParts[i]);
            if (m.find()) {
                metadata.put((String)m.group(1), (String)m.group(2));
            }
        }

        return metadata;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prepareAsync() and not prepare(). See the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#preparingasync

Comment: Mainly facing problem when i click in play button it takes more time to response if i use IcyStreamClass to show meta data otherwise it's working fine.
I think may be it's for  getMeta() method.
Did u check this method?